# base64_decode omits one byte

Tags: php, base64, byte

I'm using PHP's `base64_decode` on this string:

```
Dg+to8RaC3VzAGRThP7iiXe0f5bgp7xmcQoqaAJxggs=
```

and it should return 32 bytes of data.
But somehow I end up with a string thats only 31 bytes long.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$data = base64_decode($data);
if($data == FALSE)
{
    die("decode faild");
}
```

The problem is that the decode will actually work. But it returns only 31 bytes.
When I do this: `$len = strlen($data);`
then `$len` will contain 31 characters instead of 32.

With the following string it woks (strangely):

```
az8XFgxw/ODAr3EDElvgab/axINKVMDCrw5u51gn6bo=
```

I already tried `urlencode` after the `base64` and `urldecode` before decoding but the result was exactly the same (It worked but omited one byte)

**What am I missing?**

---

**EDIT:** I printed out all bytes. It REALLY omits the last byte! `0x0B` (the last byte) is missing but the other bytes are there.

**EDIT 2:** additional tests yield this:
1. when I embedd the base64 strings directly in the PHP file it always works.
2. when I get the `base64` string from a `$_GET` variable then it sometimes doesn't work.

is `$_GET` broken?

Comment: It looks like it's [32 bytes for me](http://viper-7.com/OKoPDk).

Comment: You totally need to urlencode your `$_GET` parameters if you use non-printable characters before `base64_encode`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. @nickb: Yes its 32bytes, but in my PHP script it returned a 31 bytes long string. Ah and urldecode should not be used, because the script will somehow automatically decode the value. (applying urldecode again will somehow trigger the error again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `+` my friend, it's being interpreted as  (space). So either `url_encode()` before appending the data to the URL and then `url_decode()` in your script or simply replace the space with `+`.

```
$data = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $data));
```

Comment: Both of your suggested solutions work. Thanks. I'm now using urlencode. But somehow urldecode is not even needed. In fact, using urldecode in the php-script will trigger the error again!! Maybe GETting the variable will auto-unencode the value ???